# Update variable outside of Parse closure

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, closures

I have a variable that I'd like to update within a closure and access outside of it. However, I'm struggling to get the data out of the closure. I have done this properly before but forgot how I did it.

Here's my code:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
    query?.whereKey("phoneNumber", containedIn: myContactsPhoneNumbers as [AnyObject])
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        for existingUser in objects! {
            self.contactsOnApp.append(existingUser)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//write one function to use upadated values , call the function from closure.

let query = PFUser.query()
query?.whereKey("phoneNumber", containedIn: myContactsPhoneNumbers as [AnyObject])
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

    for existingUser in objects! {
        self.contactsOnApp.append(existingUser)
    }
    self.functionToUseUpadatedData(self.contactsOnApp)
})

func functionToUseUpadatedData(data: AnyObject) {
   NSLog("implementation write here")
}
```